# Getting Rows Inserted After some date/time

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I need to get all the entries that were added 'today', ie 24 hours prior to the point of execution. It is simple enough to do so with date column, which I don't have. Is it at all possible to find these rows without such column?

Thanks

Comment: You either have to have logging setup, or a timestamp, if you don't have either you're out of luck. Going forward, I would suggest a timestamp column...

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or Oracle?  There is a way to do this in Oracle using `scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn)`, although it would also include any updated rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it.  If you don't have a date stamp on the row, then there's no way of knowing when it was inserted.